# When does this limit coincide with the derivative of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I am working with the following limit

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{c+1}+h\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}\right)}{h}$$

where $c$ is a constant with $0 \leq c \leq 1$. Note that $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}=\frac{1}{c+1}$$

Under what conditions on the function f will this limit coincide with the derivative of $f$ at $\frac{1}{1+c}$ (assuming this exists):

$$f'\left(\frac{1}{1+c}\right)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{c+1}+h\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{c+1}\right)}{h}$$

Comment: At least you need to ask that $f$ is differentiable at $\frac{1}{c+1}$.

Comment: Thanks. Assuming it is differentiable, is there anything further we need?

Comment: At least you need to ask that $f$ is differentiable at $\frac{1}{c+1}$, in order to use the approximation $f(1/(1+c))$ by a first order Taylor polynomial. Also, I think you will need some bounds for the speed of convergence to  $\frac{1}{c+1}$ of the expression where $f$ is evaluated.

Comment: Don't make your life harder with such a bulky constant.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f \in C^2$ so that we can use taylor's formula without concerns. We want to establish conditions on $\varepsilon(h)$ so that
$$
f'(a)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a+\varepsilon(h))}{h}
$$

Using Taylor's formula,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a+\varepsilon(h))}{h}=&\frac{1}{h}\left(f(a)+f'(a) h +\frac{f''(\xi_1)}{2} h^2 -f(a)-f'(a) \varepsilon(h) - \frac{f''(\xi_2)}{2} \varepsilon(h)^2 \right)\\
= & f'(a)-f'(a) \frac{\varepsilon(h)}{h}+\frac{f''(\xi_1)}{2} h -\frac{f''(\xi_2)}{2} \frac{\varepsilon(h)^2}{h}
\end{align*}

Making $h \to 0$,

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a+\varepsilon(h))}{h} = f'(a)-f'(a)\cdot \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\varepsilon(h)}{h} - \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f''(\xi_2)}{2} \frac{\varepsilon(h)^2}{h}
$$

So you see that if $\dfrac{\varepsilon(h)}{h} \to 0$, the proposed limit coincides with $f'(a)$.

Comment: Thank you. What are the arguments $\xi_1,\xi_2$?

Comment: @Hunt Those come from Taylor's formula. Form instance, $\xi_1 \in (a, a+h)$.

Answer (score 0):

By the MVT, there is $\xi$ between $\frac{1}{c+1}+h$ and $\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
&&f\left(\frac{1}{c+1}+h\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}\right)\\
&=&f'(\xi)\left[\left(\frac{1}{c+1}+h\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}\right)\right].
\end{eqnarray}
Let
$$ g(h)=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1)}}=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}-1\right)}(1-c^{-1)}} $$
and then $g(0)=\frac{1}{c+1}$ and
$$ g'(0)=-\frac{1}{\left[2+\sqrt{c\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}-1\right)}(1-c^{-1)}\right]^2}\cdot\frac12 \frac{1-c^{-1}}{\sqrt{c\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}-1\right)}}(-1)\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{c+1}+h)^2}\bigg|_{h=0}=\cdots$$
So
$$ g(h)=g(0)+g'(0)h+\cdots $$
and hence
$$\lim_{h->0}\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{c+1}+h\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}\right)}{h}=-f'(\frac1{c+1})\dots.$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure I'm following how you get the last step from the definition of g.

From what you wrote, I have:

$$\lim_{h->0}\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{c+1}+h\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}\right)}{h}=\lim_{h->0}\frac{-f'(\xi)(g(0)+h+g'(0)h+ O(h))}{h}$$ 

What did I get wrong?

Comment: Note that $g(h)=g(0)+g'(0)h+O(h^2)$.

Comment: Got it. Is the following correct?

$$\lim_{h->0}\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{c+1}+h\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}\right)}{h}=
\lim_{h->0}\frac{f'(\xi)\left[\left(\frac{1}{c+1}+h\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{c\frac{1-\frac{1}{c+1}-h}{\frac{1}{c+1}+h}}(1-c^{-1})}\right)\right]}{h}
=\lim_{h->0}\frac{f'(\xi)(g(0)+h-g(h))}{h}
=\lim_{h->0}\frac{f'(\xi)(g(0)+h-g(0)-g'(0)h-O(h^2))}{h}
=\lim_{h->0}\frac{f'(\xi)(h-g'(0)h-O(h^2))}{h}
=f'(\frac{1}{c+1})(1-g'(0))$$

Comment: Yes, I think so.